# Replacing a laptop hard drive - how do I choose one?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion

So I've figured out the problem with my laptop not starting up is the hard drive (since I can boot from a USB drive).

I've been looking on newegg.com to find a replacement, how do I know it's compatible? I've got an HP Pavilion dv2000. (As a side note, I've had nothing but troubles with this laptop. Sadly, it's not covered by a warranty anymore, but it hasn't worked in more than a year.)

How can I be sure I'm buying the right hard drive? I'm looking for a cheap drive, meaning not too many gb. The computer won't be used to store much, so there's not much use in extra drive space. Also, would I be able to buy a cheap SSD (by cheap, I mean less gb so the overall cost is low, I know they're expensive pieces of hardware). Or does the computer have to be built to use SSD drives?

Comment: Were you able to upgrade your laptop with a new HD? Did you choose SSD or HHD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hard drive is fine as long as it got Sata interface and the 2.5" notebook hdd size. It can be SSD, HDD, whatever you want. Even 7200rpm if that is what you need. (I'd only worry if you choose a 1.5 or 2TB big HDD (IF THERE IS ONE for laptops. I don't know.) .. But that's it.)

Comment: A 7200rpm drive might run too hot for some laptops, I don't know if this would be an issue here. And some newer SATA drives don't work with older firmware (e.g. some SATA-2 drives don't work or require a jumper or a BIOS upgrade in SATA-1 machines); again I don't know if this would be an issue on this model. But mostly, as long as it's SATA and 2.5", it'll work.

Comment: So is it better to get a 5400? Can you tell the speed difference? This laptop has had an overheating problem in the past. (Using it for 10 minutes after it turns on and only internet browsing or writing documents will cause it to get extremely hot).

Comment: Yepp, there is a difference in speed. However, if you really had heating issues, stay with the 5400 RPM one. Sorry that I didn't mention these (didn't know I should).

Comment: One thing to look at is z height. The traditional and less common size is 9mm. Most modern drives are 7mm and drive slots are sized for that

Answer (score 0):

SAMSUNG SSD For the Win! **(their software makes cloning a windows installation to their SSD's as easy as possible)**

Your laptop uses a SATA hard drive connection, ANY laptop hard drive is going to fit this machine.

But seriously, upgrade to a suitably sized Samsung 860 EVO SSD, and you can use their software to clone your existing disk to the new drive.

I have done this 10+ times, and it has been painless, and the users were overjoyed with the resulting performance improvement of an SSD.

**Using the Samsung software you can even go from a 1TB HDD to something smaller like a 512GB SSD, provided you were not using more than half of the Terabyte drive.** (attempting this using other software I have had mixed results, and NEVER straightforward. Sometimes Windows will refuse to let you shrink the C:\ partition past a certain point, and most software does not support cloning a partition to smaller partition)

When you get a new computer in the future, you can always take the SSD out of the old machine to continue using it.

[EDIT: Highlighting the benefits of Samsung SSD over other Mfrs, and IMO it's the migration software, and also the peace of mind of a solid reputation backed up by a pretty good warranty]

Comment: Why Samsung vs. the endless other brands?  The accepted answer already suggests that an SSD can be used.  So this answer is really just a plug for a specific brand.  As such, it should focus on why you're recommending that brand over all others.  If there's a legitimate technical reason that you can support with a citation, that's fine.  If it's just personal preference, anecdotal experience, or you're shilling for Samsung (kinda reads like Samsung spam), then it isn't the kind of fact-based answer that the site looks for.  As-is, I suspect that this answer may attract downvotes.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, "you can use their software to clone your existing disk to the new drive."

This may not seem like a big deal, but coming from somebody who has used CloneZilla (an awesome piece of software btw), the Samsung Migration Software is Hands-Down WAY WAY WAY easier to Clone a windows HDD to SSD. ESPECIALLY if you are going from a larger HDD to smaller SSD.

Literally my dad could use this software (and he is a mac user)...

Also, Samsung's drives have a solid reputation, and my own experiences back that up.